# fixed length flat file without separators

Tags: python, flat-file

I have a comprehension question not related to any particular language, but since I am writing in python, I tagged python. I am asked to provide some data in "fixed length, flatfile without separators". It confuses me, since I understand it like:

```
Input: Column A: date (len6)

Input: Column B: name (len20)

Output: "20170409MYVERYSHORTNAME[space][space][space][space][space]"
```

"MYVERYSHORTNAME" is only 15 char long, but since it's fixed 20-length output, I am supposed to fill 5 times it with something ? It's not specified.

Why do someone even needs a file without separators? He/she will need to break it down to separated fields anyway, what's the point?

Comment: the point is probably to be able to read it in binary as a size-fixed fields file (database)

Comment: Some framework may be requiring this format for example ISO8583.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of flat (binary) file is meant to be faster/easier to read by machines, and more memory efficient than the equivalent in a more human friendly representation (eg, JSON, CSV, etc.). For example, the machine can preallocate the appropriate amount of memory before reading the contents.
Nowadays, with the virtually unlimited quantity of RAM and dynamic nature of the languages, nobody uses flat files anymore (unless it is specifically needed).

In Python, in order to deal properly with this kind of binary files, you can for example use the `struct` module from the standard library:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html#module-struct

Example:

```
import struct
from datetime import datetime
mydate = datetime.now()
myshortname = "HelloWorld!"

struct.pack("8s20s", mydate.strftime('%Y%m%d').encode(), myshortname.encode())

>>> b'201709HelloWorld!\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Could you please confirm I have to padd not-long-enough fields with spaces at right, and not-long-enough-numbers with zeros at left?

Comment: Yes, you have to pad any value that is not long enough to go in each field. Now the padding side and padding character is up to you (that's a design decision), you just have to be consistent between writing and reading. Usually numbers are left padded with 0 or null character, and strings are right padded with null characters (null character = a character where all bits are 0).

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when you see fixed-length files, you're dealing with legacy systems. The AS400, for instance, usually spits out fixed-length files with artificial separators (why, I don't know, but that's what I've seen).

Usually, strings are right-padded with spaces, and numbers are left-padded with 0's (zeros).

This is not absolute.